# Pull data from multiple tables in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new in Ruby on Rails and I am trying to make a book registration website. Everything works fine except category section. When a user assign a category to his book, my database copies `book_categories.id` and put it in `book.book_categories_id`. The website also have a profile page, where you can view user's book(s). My problem is to display a `category.name`, I searched a lot of similar problems but I have not found the right answer.

Here is my book controller:

```
before_action :set_book, except: [:index, :new, :create]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

def show
  @photos = @book.photos
end

def index
  @books = current_user.books
end

def new
  @book = current_user.books.build
end

def create
  @book = current_user.books.build(books_params)
  if @book.save
    redirect_to listing_book_path(@book), notice: "Saved."
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Failed."
    render :new
  end
end

private 
  def set_book
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end

  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:book_categories_id, :book_name, :summary, :address, :price, :company_name)
  end
```

As long as I understand, I have to allow my controller to have access to my category table but I do not know how. Also, all of my categories store in `seed.rb`.

This is my `BookCategory.rb` model:

```
class BookCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, :foreign_key => :book_categories_id
end
```

`Book.rb` model:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  has_many :photos, dependent: :delete_all

  validates :book_name, presence: true
  validates :book_categories_id, presence: true

  def cover_photo
    if self.photos.length > 0
      self.photos[0].image.url
    else
      "default/image-default.jpg"
    end
  end

end
```

My schema.rb:

```
create_table "book_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "subcategory"
  t.text "description"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "book", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "book_name"
  t.text "summary"
  t.string "address"
  t.decimal "price", precision: 8, scale: 2
  t.boolean "active"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.float "latitude"
  t.float "longitude"
  t.string "company_name"
  t.integer "book_categories_id"
  t.index ["book_categories_id"], name: "index_books_on_book_categories_id"
end
```

Usually, when I type `@book_categories.name`, I get an error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

And at the very end, it says `Parameters: {"id"=>"15"}` whereas the `category.id` is different, and it passes `book.id` instead.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This seems to be a very simple question to answer, but I hesitate because your code confuses me. For example why is the class name for your Book model `Service` not `Book`?

Comment: Several things: first, your class names are `Service` and `ServiceCategory` instead of `Book` and `BookCategory`.  Is this a typo?  If not, you need to define the `class_name` on your associations.  You mentioned that your `books` table has a `book_category_id` but the foreign key on your `ServiceCategory` model is `book_categories_id`.  This needs to match the name of the column in your database table.  Third, please show the code that sets `@book_categrories`.   The error you are getting is because `@book_categories` is `nil`.

Comment: @TomAranda Code updated, thank you.

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi, I am sorry. You right. It was my mistake. I updated the code, thank you.

Comment: I still don't see where `@book_categories` is being set.  Did you mean `@book.categories`?  Still, you do not have this relation on the `Book` model.

Comment: @AnthonyBrooks in your first paragraph you still have inconsistencies. Probably where you say "my database copies `category.id` and put it in `book.category_id`" you should have said "my database copies `book_categories.id` and puts it in `book.book_categories_id`". Ironically this first paragraph has the correct naming conventions and your actual code gets the naming conventions all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First fix the naming problem you have going. I don't know how the books table got called "book" instead of "books" in the schema, but you might have to fix that first.

Then category should be singular everywhere except the database table name. You need to make a migration to fix the foreign key and its index in the books table something like this:

```
class FixCategoryNaming < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :books, :book_categories_id
    add_reference :books, :book_category, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Then run `rails db:migrate` and check the schema looks ok

Then in the `BookCategory` class change the line to simply

```
has_many :books
```

You need to add this line to your `Book` class

```
belongs_to :book_category
```

and change the validation for book_category to be this

```
validates :book_category_id, presence: true
```

Then in the view for book index you have a `@books` variable. You can get the book name and category name for each book like this:

```
<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <p><%= book.book_name %></p>
  <p><%= book.book_categories.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am getting an error `undefined method book_categories`. Do I have to use `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Also, thank you for the advice, I will rename my table. Really appreciate.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show how to do some of the name fixing. You can keep the `book_` prefix on category if you want, but you really need to get the singular and plural thing right.

Comment: Are you sure that the book table is named `book` not `books`? It really should be named `books`. Double-check that.

Comment: Thank you! I spent so much time to figure it out... Thank you for your help and time Toby.

Comment: I am sorry for being annoying. I did exactly what you told me to do (also renamed my table to `categories`). So, I can easily display `@book.category.id` and get what I want but when I change it to `@book.category.name`, I am getting an error `undefined method `name' for #<Book:0x007fed5283cfd8>`, can you please tell me what I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Also, just to make it clear, in my `Book` controller, I also have `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help further without seeing your code as it is now.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to setup as `has_many through` relationship. This is a good place to start http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: There is no indication in the question that the OP wants each book to have more than one category. Given that each book has one category the `has_many through` relationship is not appropriate.

Comment: I took the name `BookCategories` and implied that it was a join table.  My mistake.